# Django REST API - SerializerMethodField() causes too many queries

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I am a bit lost here. I have created a nested relationship that goes as follows: Text -> multiple Sentences-> multiple Words

models.py:

```
class Text(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Sentence(models.Model):
    text = models.ForeignKey(Text, related_name='sentences', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['text', 'order']
        ordering = ['order']

class Word(models.Model):
    sentence = models.ForeignKey(Sentence, related_name='words', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    word = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
    vocabulary = models.ForeignKey(Vocabulary, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['sentence', 'order']
        ordering = ['order']

class Vocabulary(models.Model):
    vocabulary = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class KnownWords(models.Model):
    vocabulary = models.ForeignKey(Vocabulary, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The idea is that a text is split into individual words. Each word is associated with a vocabulary and users can know the vocabulary.

serializer.py:

```
class WordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_known = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Word
        fields = ['id', 'order', 'word', 'vocabulary', 'is_known ']

    def get_is_known(self, obj):
        if KnownWords.objects.filter(vocabulary=obj.vocabulary).exists():
            obj.is_known = True
        else:
            obj.is_known = False
        return obj.is_known
    
class SentenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    words = WordSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Sentence
        fields = ['id', 'order', 'words']

class TextSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sentences = SentenceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Text
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'sentences']
```

views.py:

```
class TextDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Text.objects.prefetch_related('sentences', 'sentences__words')
    serializer_class = TextSerializer
```

The reason why `ìs_known` is a `SerializerMethodField` is that i eventually want to filter this for each user. But here is my problem. I get one additional query for each word as it needs to check if the word is present in KnownWords. For longer texts i easily get 100+ queries and querytimes of 3000+ ms. I can not wrap my head around wether there is a way to prefetch the whole KnownWord data somewhere in my views or elsewhere. Sorry if the answer is obvious! And thanks in advance!